# Read integers and words into array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have file that has numbers and words and all ends with  -1
how would i go about putting it into an array 
for example;

so in the `file.dat` i have it has something like

```
6 5 yo moma 5 6 -1

9 sup chicken 2 5 -1

...
```

and i want to put the first line into one array and the seconds line into another arrays and so on 
so something like this

`array_1[]` would have **6 5 yo moma 5 6** in it

`array_2[]` would have **9 sup chicken 2 5** in it
and so on

so how would i go about doing this.

Comment: See [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 2):

Since the input file contains a mix of numbers and words, you need a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >` to store them.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::ifstream infile("file.dat");
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > result;
int lineCount = 0;
std::string line;

while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    int current i = 0;
    // "line.size() - 3" because all data lines end with " -1"
    for (int j = 0; j < line.size() - 3; ++j)
    {
        if (line[j] == ' ')
        {
            result[lineCount].push_back(line.substr(i, j - i));
            i = j + 1;
        }
    }
    ++lineCount;
}
```